# Javascript trouble with .show after hide it

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

can someone help me, i have some javascript problem, i just want to hide $('#uploaded_image'), and i can do it with .hide(); but after that, i want to show it again with onclick="$(#uploaded_image).html.show(); in html tags inside javascript, but it still hide, what i must do then??? here's the code:

```
$('#a').hide();
$('#thumbnail_form').hide();
$('#uploaded_image').hide();
$('#a').show().html('<input type="button" value="  Ok  " onclick="window.location.reload()">&nbsp;For Crop<input type="button" value="Click Here" onclick="$(#uploaded_image).html.show();">');

$('#uploaded_image').html('<table><tr><td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" width="600px" height="600px" style="border:solid #999999; border-radius:8px; border-width:1px;">
<center><h2><font color="#333333">Select Image Area For Crop</font></h2>
<img src="' + responseMsg + '" style="border:solid #999999; border-width:1px;" id="thumbnail" alt="Create Thumbnail" /></center><br></td></tr></table>')
```

Sorry For my bad language, i'm not an europeans...

Comment: I'm going to leave this here and hopefully you can read it, it may help you improve your development practices http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax in your onclick handler is wrong and you also forgot the quotation marks:

```
onclick="$(#uploaded_image).html.show();">
```

Replace it with

```
onclick="$(\'#uploaded_image\').show();">
```

Comment: wow, it's working, thank you very much :D
i just think it must be onclick="javascript:" but after see your answer it wasn't like i think, thanks.. :D

Comment: you only need to add `javascript:` if you put it into the `href` attribute (which is not recommended)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this `$(#uploaded_image).html.show()` do this `$('#uploaded_image').show()`

You apply the [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) or [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to the selected element, not to its contents.
Also, don't forget the quotes (see the second part)

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is wrong, `$(#uploaded_image).html.show()`. You are missing quotes & `html` is not needed since you dont want to set any content.

If you want to just show the element again use `$(\'#uploaded_image\').show()`

Comment: wow, it's working,
i just think it must be onclick="javascript:" but after see your answer it wasn't like i think, thanks.. :D